# Google Spreadsheets Dropdown Lists

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm using Spreadsheets to tabulate some data. I have 2 sheets, one that displays everything with drop down lists, and the second that has the information.

The second sheet looks like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
|  Character  |    Type     |         Gear1         |            Gear2            |          Gear3          |         Gear4          |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
|   Ultron    |  Universal  |  Concussion Blasters  |       Vibranium Shell       |  Small Nuclear Reactor  |  Hive-Mind Technology  |
|   Vision    |  Universal  |     Solar Energy      |  Density Alteration System  |   Self-Repair System    |    Optical Scanners    |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

The first sheet has a drop down list to select the character. Once the character is selected, I want to display something else in the same row as the selected character.

I'm struggling to find a way to do this without a tonne of IF statements. What is the most effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out by playing around with the functions.

If your dropdown list cell is `C2`, use the following:

```
VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!A:F,2,FALSE)
```

That will get the 2nd column of the row where the 1st column matches the dropdown list.